# Is the Euclidean group $E(3)$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ amenable?

Tags: group-theory, amenability

I am quite confused about this since I thought the Banach-Tarski theorem implies it is not but I also heard from multiple people that it is amenable since it is the semidirect product of an abelian and a compact group. It would be amazing if someone could explain the relationship between amenable groups and the paradox to me! I would also be interested in the amenability of $E(d)$ for general $d$.

Comment: What topology do you put on this group? Discrete or natural Lie group topology? The answer will depend on that.

Comment: The natural topology based on how it acts on Euclidean space

Comment: Then it is amenable. It is nonamenable when equipped with discrete topology. The BT paradox treats this group as a discrete group. You have to read the proof to understand this. There are many places where this proof is written.

Comment: @MoisheKohan So the Banach-Tarski paradox is based on the discrete topology?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Cool, thank you! Sorry, I read your previous comment before you edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to think about the group $SO(3)$. If you equip it with the natural matrix topology, it is compact, hence amenable: The invariant probability measure is the natural one, given by a left-invariant volume form on this Lie group. (There is a lot to digest here if you do not know what these words mean.) But as a discrete group, $SO(3)$ is not amenable since it contains a free group on two generators and the latter is nonamenable. The existence of nonabelian free subgroups is the heart of the proof of the Banach-Tarski paradox. Again, it requires quite a bit of work on your part to understand what am I talking about if you are not familiar with these notions.